# Default storage issue in some android phone

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app2sd

Does android jelly bean 4.1.2 not supports to move the apps from internal storage of phone to external micro sd card but android jelly bean 4.2.2 or 4.3 can?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Some phone manufacturers adds the feature of moving apps to sd card in some of their models but most of them does not have this feature by default. Although you can change that manually by rooting your phone and using an app called 'app2sd ' on any version of Android .

Comment: The [app2sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) feature was added to Android back with Froyo (Android 2.2). My feeling is rather that some manufacturers *removed* it, while stock still has it. But I cannot name a source for that. Do you have a source to name for your variant?